# read text file and put into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out to read a file with multiple line and split the third line as keys and the fourth line as their value

**file.txt**

```
Ext: aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh 
tcp: 000 111 222 333 444 555 666 777 
Ext: kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr 
tcp: 222 555 444 666 888 958 555 454
```

and desired output like this:

```py
{
    "kkk" : "222",
    "lll" : "555",
    "mmm" : "444",
    "nnn" : "666",
    "ooo" : "888",
    "ppp" : "958",
    "qqq" : "555",
    "rrr" : "454"
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempt through some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fp:
    lines = [e.strip() for e in fp.readlines()]
    my_dict = {l3 :l4 for l3, l4 in zip(lines[2].split()[1:], lines[3].split()[1:])}

print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'kkk': '222', 'lll': '555', 'mmm': '444', 'nnn': '666', 'ooo': '888', 'ppp': '958', 'qqq': '555', 'rrr': '454'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a simpler solution, but that is what I would do

```
file = open("path_to_your_file.txt", "r")
file.readline()
file.readline()
keys = file.readline().split()[1:]
values = file.readline().split()[1:]
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
file.close()
print(d)
```

And that is the output:

```
{'ooo': '888', 'ppp': '958', 'nnn': '666', 'lll': '555', 'kkk': '222', 'rrr': '454', 'mmm': '444', 'qqq': '555'}
```